# How can i access vars from upper scope - javascript

Tags: javascript

ia have a problem. How can i get access to my vars in TeslaModelS from the prototype extension ?

Or is my Plugin-Pattern wrong ?

I would like to separate the different areas of my app and not have it all in one big file

```js
var TeslaModelS = function () {
    this.numWheels = 4;
    this.manufacturer = 'Tesla';
    this.make = 'Model S';

    this.Drive.pressGasPedal();
}

TeslaModelS.prototype = function () {
    var _this = this;

    var Drive = {
        go: function () {
          // HOW CAN I GET RED AND WRITE ACCESS TO MY VARS IN TeslaModelS ??
            console.log(_this.numWheels)
        },

        stop: function () {
        }
    }

    return {
        Drive: {
            pressBrakePedal: Drive.stop,
            pressGasPedal: Drive.go
        }
    }

}();

var i = new TeslaModelS();
```

Comment: You have to create a class in the name of `Drive`, then extend it from `TesaModelS`

Comment: Sorry but this.numWheels is also undefined ...

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy can you pls provide a sample ?

Comment: Why not just assign a something directly to `TeslaModelS.prototype.Drive`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. Just figured. We will have to bind context to it

Comment: "*I would like to not have it all in one big file*" - that's no reason to nest prototype properties at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, with the structure you've created. I would suggest using a more normal structure:

```js
// The constructor function
var TeslaModelS = function() {
  this.numWheels = 4;
  this.manufacturer = 'Tesla';
  this.make = 'Model S';

  this.pressGasPedal();
};

TeslaModelS.prototype.pressGasPedal = function() {
  console.log(this.numWheels);
};

TeslaModelS.prototype.pressBrakePedal = function() {
};

var i = new TeslaModelS();
```

But if you don't want to, if you really want that `Drive` object, you'll need to create bound versions of those functions on a distinct `Drive` object for each instance:

```js
// The functions you'll bind each time
var Drive = {
  go: function() {
    console.log(this.numWheels)
  },

  stop: function() {}
};

// The constructor function
var TeslaModelS = function() {
  this.numWheels = 4;
  this.manufacturer = 'Tesla';
  this.make = 'Model S';

  // Create a Drive object for this instance with the functions bound
  // to `this`
  this.Drive = {
    pressGasPedal: Drive.go.bind(this),
    pressBrakePedal: Drive.stop.bind(this)
  };

  this.Drive.pressGasPedal();
}

var i = new TeslaModelS();
```

Comment: Hm... i really want it because i want to seperate my application with this a little bit more.

This bound thing is way complicated isnt it ? is there no other pattern which i can use ?

Comment: @DerMakkuz: It's not that complicated. It was complicated a bit by the fact you've used different names for the properties (`pressGasPedal` vs. `go`), but you could use a loop to create the bound functions. But consider, what if I do `var t1 = new TeslaModelS(); var t2 = new TeslaModelS(); t1.Drive = t2.Drive;` Now we've got weird cross-talk. That's why I would stick to a normal pattern (not to mention being well-supported by tools, dramatically simpler syntax if you use ES2015 [transpiling if necessary], etc.).